# Change variable used in mixin depending on scope

Tags: less

In the [Lazy Loading](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-lazy-loading) section of the Less language features, it states:

> When defining a variable twice, the last definition of the variable is used, searching from the current scope upwards. This is similar to css itself where the last property inside a definition is used to determine the value.

I'd like to overwrite a global variable, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
@border: #fff;

.table {
  border: @border;
}

.table-summary {
  @border: #000;
  .table
}
```

Compiles to

```
.table {
  border: #ffffff;
}
.table-summary {
  border: #ffffff; // I want this to be #000
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the global scope has higher precedence than caller scope for a mixin (unless the mixin is defined inside parametric namespace). For more more details see [#1316](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1316#issuecomment-26682476), some people consider this is a bug but there's no well-defined agreement on that.

Either way, the recommendation is to [minimize use of non-parametric mixins](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1399#issuecomment-33680478) and to not rely on indirect parameter passing whenever possible. Your example is a perfect use-case for a parametric mixin (even if your the code becomes slightly more verbose):

```css
@border-default: #fff;

.table-base(@border: @border-default) {
    border: @border;
}

.table {
    .table-base;
}

.table-summary {
    .table-base(#000); 
}
```

**Alt.** if for some reason you can't modify the `.table` class (for example if it's defined in an external library) then just forget about any variables and override the property directly, the most optimal way would be:

```css
@border: #fff;

.table {
    border: @border;
}

.table-summary:extend(.table) {
    border-color: #000;
}
```

### ---

Technically, there's method to achieve what you want with the code quite close to your original snippet but I doubt it is something to be really recommended:

```css
@border: #fff;

.table {
    border: @border;
}

.-;.-() { // dummy parametric namespace

.table-summary {
    @border: #000;
    .table;
}

} // end of dummy parametric namespace
```

Comment: I'm trying to add customizations to a library, so unfortunately I do not have the luxury of editing the parameters of the mixin.

Comment: Then it's better to use radically different approach, see updated answer.

Comment: What is it that you're doing in the last example?

Comment: That basically calls mixin with `.-` name and then defines this `.-` mixin (so it behaves like unique scope with its content expanded into global scope but with `caller > global` scope precedence priority).